# How to embed exit code in error to use when terminating program?

Tags: go

How can I embed an exit code in a go error, bubble it up, and then exit with the exit code when I handle the error?

For example:

```
func main () {
  foo, err := foo()
  if err != nil{
    fmt.Printf("error thrown, exit code: %v", err )
  }
  // I can parse the exit code out of err, but that seems wrong... 
  // how can I exit with the exit code cleanly? do i need to create a custom error that I bubble up and handle?
  os.Exit(1)
}

func foo() (string, err) {
  bar, err := bar()
  if err != nil {
     return "", fmt.Errorf("foo fails b/c bar fails %v": err)
  }
}

func bar() (string, err) {
  exitCode := 208
  return "", fmt.Errorf("some error happened in bar, exit code: %v", exitCode)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by creating your own type that implements the `error` interface and then using error wrapping (see [this blog post](https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors) for more info). The result is something like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

type fooErr int

func (e fooErr) Error() string { return strconv.Itoa(int(e)) }

func main() {
    errCode := 0
    _, err := foo()
    if err != nil {
        var e fooErr
        if errors.As(err, &e) {
            fmt.Printf("error thrown, exit code: %v", e)
            errCode = int(e)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("error thrown, dont have a code: %v", err)
            errCode = 1 // default code...
        }
    }
    // I can parse the exit code out of err, but that seems wrong...
    // how can I exit with the exit code cleanly? do i need to create a custom error that I bubble up and handle?
    os.Exit(errCode)
}

func foo() (string, error) {
    _, err := bar()
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("foo fails b/c bar fails %w", err)
    }
    return "OK", nil
}

func bar() (string, error) {
    exitCode := fooErr(208)
    return "", fmt.Errorf("some error happened in bar, exit code: %w", exitCode)
}
```

Try it in [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Wl3knpgRIbA).